# Dialog fragment used for two different dialogs

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

So I implemened a custom class that inherits DialogFragment. I want to use this dialog for two types of operations: delete and edit. For that I customized it so for each one I set the title, description and button text. What I want to do is to create an interface and have two presenters: DeletePresenter and EditPresenter that implements that interface. The interface shoul have the click action and the setting of texts for dialog. Being very new to this I can't figure it out how do I connect all of them (dialogFragment, presenters and interface)? If anyone could give me an example that would be great.

**MyDialogFragment**

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private DialogPresenterContract dialogPresenterContract;

    private String title, description, buttonTxt;

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.dialog_btn:
            dialogPresenterContract.onActionClick(editText.getText().toString().trim(), onDialogActionListener);
            break;          
    }
}
```

**DialogPresenterContract**

```
public interface DialogPresenterContract {

    void onActionClick(String reason, MyDialogFragment.OnDialogActionListener onDialogActionListener);

    String getDialogTitle();

    String getDialogDescription();

    String getDialogButtonTxt();

}
```

**DeletePresenter**

```
 public class DeletePresenter implements DialogPresenterContract {
   //implement all methods
 }
```

**EditPresenter**

```
  public class EditPresenter implements DialogPresenterContract {
      //implement all methods
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want MVP try my sample below, but if you have not match logic I recommend write her right in your view(MyDialogFragment).

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener, MyView {

    public static MyDialogFragment newInstance(int num) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("type", type);
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        presenter.setType(getArguments().getInt("type"));
        ...
    }

    private Presenter presenter;

    private String title, description, buttonTxt;

    @override
    void setStrings(String title, String description, String buttonTitle) {
      ......
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.dialog_btn:
          dialogPresenterContract.onActionClick(editText.getText().toString().trim());
            break;          
        }
    }
}
```

MyView interface

```
interface MyView {
    void setStrings(String title, String description, String buttonTitle); 
}
```

Presenter

```
class Presenter {

    private MyView view;
    private int type;

    public Presenter(MyView view) {
       this.view = view;
    }

    void setType(int type) {
       this.type = type;
    }

    void onClick(String text) {
       if (type == delete_type) {
         .....
        } else {
         ......
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to do it MVP, that's what I'm saying

Comment: @alexC then try my sample which is above